# Библейские насекомые

Tags: значение-слов

В вопросе про лапы-ноги behemothus процитировал Левит, и там меня заинтересовала одна строчка: "сих ешьте из них: саранчу с ее породою, солам с ее породою, харгол с ее породою и хагаб с ее породою".
Так вот, интересно, кто такие "солам", "харгол" и "хагаб"? А еще, по-моему, в Откровении Иоанна Богослова упоминаются некие "скнипы", нашествие которых расценивается как одно из бедствий Апокалипсиса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"солам", "харгол" и "хагаб" скорее всего - это разные виды или разные названия саранчи. Всего у саранчи в Танахе насчитывается до десятка названий.

Что касается названия скнипы, то вероятнее всего это просто искаженное многочисленными переводами обозначение все той же саранчи, с которой, к тому, славяне были не слишком хорошо знакомы. Вряд ли какое-либо другое насекомое могло играть столь роковую роль в жизни древних народов Средиземноморья.

А где все-таки в Апокалипсисе упоминается скнипы? Сколько не смотрю - везде саранча. 
Так что тут что-то не так.
В Исходе и Псалтире, согласен, речь идет о каких-то кровососущих мошках (комары? москиты?), но там и контекст другой.

Comment: Пс. 104:31 "Он сказал, и пришли разные насекомые, **скнипы** во все пределы их"


Пс. 104:34 "Сказал, и пришла саранча и гусеницы без числа"

Это перечисление казней египетских, там и саранча, и "скнипы" сама же "казнь" описана в Исх. 8:17-18

>Аарон простер руку свою с жезлом своим и ударил в персть земную, и явились мошки на людях и на скоте. Вся персть земная сделалась мошками по всей земле Египетской. Старались также и волхвы чарами своими произвести мошек, но не могли. И были мошки на людях и на скоте.

Здесь, скнипы переведены как "мошки", и саранчу их поведение никак не напоминает.

Comment: А на что похоже? Не нельзя ж так голой

Comment: Так в Апокалипсисе никаких "скнипов" нету, там и язык-то другой, с греческим таких проблем нет, так как много источников. Автор вопроса спутал книги.

Comment: Я рад, что Вы это поняли))). Только я без Апокалипсиса и отвечать бы не стал. Ибо неактуально. 

Хотя я не стал бы так безапелляционно заявлять что-то про автора, не спросив его мнения.

Comment: Ну, автор и написал "кажется, в Откровении". И, по-моему, суть не в том, в какой из Книг упоминается это слово, а в том, что оно означает.  
Кстати, мне тоже кажется, что это вид саранчи, а не кровососов. Потому что от нашествия комаров можно защититься, а вот саранча оставляет целые страны без урожая, обрекая людей на голод, а это уже посерьезнее.
Кстати, в прошлом году у нас было нашествие саранчи - к людям в окна залетала, на улицах сидела целыми кучами.

Comment: Откровение Иоана - это и сеть "Апокалипсис".
Суть вопроса - возможно не в этом, но я-то, поверив, автору, пытался объяснить появление слова именно там, а "Откровении", ибо оно явно не вписывается в тамошнюю текстологию.  
Ради же толкования Ветхого Завета я не стал бы этим заниматься, ибо текстологических противоречий не порождает, да и дело это заведомо неблагодарное, каббалистика - она и есть каббалистика.   
Да, забыл. В десяти казнях египетских упоминаются не только саранча, но и "мошки", а так же мухи-псы (оводы?). Это ***три разные*** казни. Но до апокалиптических масштабов тут далеко.

Comment: Интересный тут выбор правильных ответов. Получается, из комментария @Fuchoin Kazuki, что Ваш ответ выбрали потому, что Вы предложили версию, которую теперь и сами признали неверной.

Comment: У меня такого не получается. 
Почему выбрали - не знаю. У меня есть определенные сомнения в отношении здешнего подхода к "выбору" - я об этом говорил. Причем и я кто-то невольно "обижал" - и меня.   
Но тутошний ответ свой я не считаю неправильным.

Answer (score 1):

*Скнипы* в старорусском наречии означает "вши", но в других переводах книги здесь стоит: комары, мошки.

Кто такие *солам, харгол и хагаб* можно судить лишь приблизительно, так как других упоминаний о них до нас не дошло. По "Библейской энциклопедии Брокгауза" Ф. Ринекер, Г. Майер. Это наименование неизвестных нам видов саранчи. Хотя попадалось мнение, что это кузнечики и жуки. Доподлинно неизвестно.

Answer (score 1):

Доподлинно неизвестно. Про первые три вида насекомых (солам, харгол и хагаб) мы знаем только то, что они съедобные (кроме Левита никаких упоминаний о них нет), а про скнипов нам известно, что они не саранча, так как она упоминается ниже, и по всей видимости неприятна как человеку, так и скоту (Исх. 8;16-19), что тоже не густо. Скорей всего скнипы - кровососы, комары или кто-то в этом роде.

Comment: В Левите - это вряд ли.    
Упоминания есть в Исходе и Псалтири.  
Что-то уже становится дурной традицией путать книги Заветов. )))

Comment: @behemothus, чуть  было не запутали, даже отредактировал с испугу )). Скнипы, да, упоминаются только в этих местах, но "первые три вида насекомых" в вопросе - это солам, харгол и хагаб, а они упомянуты только в 11 главе Левита, 22 стих.

Comment: Ну извините, коли так. Но вообще-то тогда стоило написать, какие три вида имеются в виду. Во всяком случае Вы-то меня явно запутали.

Comment: Исправил, хотя из контекста вопрос-ответ вроде и так понятно.

Comment: Солам - саранчовые; харгол - саранча перелетная; хагаб - настоящие сверчки. Из ит перевода Левита.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего скнипы - кровососы, комары или кто-то в этом роде.
Согласен с высказыванием.
Мне кажется, что "скнип" - это слепень в современном названии.

Answer (score 0):

СКНИПЫ . Даю скриншот из "Полного церковно-славянского словаря " Гр. Дьяченко ;стр.607 /ссылка [ПЦСС стр.607](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0607.htm) . Про солам , харгол и хагаб там не нашёл. [image: скнипы - скриншот]

Comment: Видимо, не всегда стоит верить даже канонизированным версиям. "Вши" как-то не очень смотрится...

Answer (score 0):

Это маленькие типа комариков, но похуже и очень долго укусы остаются, и пятна если расчесали, а у кого слабый иммунитет могут разносить средиземноморскую лихорадку. Они летом когда жарко. Кусаются конечно, и местные жители именно называют их скнипы. Я только сегодня вспомнила, что это слово встречается в Псалтири:)

Comment: Какое именно слово Вы встречали в Псалтыри? И какое из трех вы приравгяли к скнипам?